# SVN to Git migration: fixing bad branch structure

Tags: git, svn

We have migrated (using git svn) a large repo from SVN to Git, and screwed up.

The SVN repo has an unusual branch structure:

```
 trunk
 branches
   developers
     john
     peter
     mary
   tickets
     0123456
     6543210
```

(it's just an example, not the actual branch structure)

Unfortunately the migration process created only two branches, "trunk" and "branches", and everything was lumped as a folder under "branches".

So instead of

```
 remotes/origin/master
 remotes/origin/john
 remotes/origin/peter
 remotes/origin/mary
 remotes/origin/0123456
 remotes/origin/6543210
```

we have

```
 remotes/origin/master
 remotes/origin/branches
```

and under `remotes/origin/branches` we have *folders* `developers/john` and `developers/peter` and all the rest, containing copies of the respective SVN branches.

Is there a way to fix this quickly (i.e. convert folders back to branches) without doing the whole migration process all over again?

Comment: This branch structure is not bad. The problem is with Git actually just because it limits branches to a single namespace.

Comment: @bahrep This is not a problem, I'm OK with flattening branches like that. The problem is that for each file in branch `master`, say `project/main.c`, we have `developers/peter/project/main.c` and `developers/john/project/main.c` and all the rest of them (hundreds) in branch `branches`. I want to fix this. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You should mention what tool you used for your migration. (and not listen to the first comment)

Comment: @ThibaultD.git svn...

Comment: @ThibaultD. and what's wrong with the first comment? Git does not support multiple namespaces for branches. If there are branches with the same names under /developers or /tickets, the migration is going to be a pain. Just noting one of the major benefits of SVN over Git.

Comment: Not sure what you call a namespace. The relationship between branches in Git probably makes it useless to have. But its rather common for people to name their branches with _folders_, for exemple _feature/crispier_cookies_ or _feature/warmer_water_ as some graphical tools will group them under a _feature_ folder.

Comment: What's wrong with the first comment, you've found out yourself: You have the same file multiple times. Then there's no point using git branches. There's no files in Git, a commit is a summary of the changes of the files and a branch is a list of commit. Branches share the same commits up to the point where they differ, and when a merge is performed they share the same commits again. If you have the same file in separate folders like in SVN in your Git folder, then you won't be able to experience the power of Git.

Comment: I suggest checking if your export tool can handle branches better, if you exported without the history then you should create a new branch from master (for example feature/peter), wipe the files (except the .git/) and copy the contents of developer/peter/ into the root of the project, git add all and then commit. Repeat for each branch.

Comment: @ThibaultD. Tried this, but the repo is simply too large. "branches" is hundreds of real branches, the total size huge, checking out takes ages and I don't have enough disk space to keep all of these identical copies of files...

Comment: @n.m. That's interesting. But you could do that on another computer? Do you really wish to export all branches? Once you've correctly git-ified your branches, the good thing is that a whole copy of the repo won't take much more than twice the size of a branch. If you add all branches in Git like you did you'll have that disk space problem. You could SVN-checkout branches one by one, add to git, remove the SVN copy and so on.

Comment: @ThibaultD. I actually ended up cloning again from scratch with correct -branch parameters. Took a lot of time. I tried to checkout branches one by one, and it would take much longer. In fact if fetching with all history, fetching all branches and fetching a single branch take comparable time.